# Линейный конгруэнтный генератор

Tags: c, математика, криптография

Как сделать цикл максимальной длины? Как правильно выбирать параметры для конгруэнтной последовательности?

```
Xₙ₊₁ = (a * Xₙ + c) mod m
```

Comment: Можно поискать у Кнута, второй том, одна из первых глав...

Comment: [Оно](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8D%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4#%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE_%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B)?

Comment: Сделать цикл максимальной длины - while(1){}. Правильно выбираются параметры под задачу, а еще лучше - использовать готовое.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, искал - не понял, можешь объяснить обеспечение максимальной мощности ЛКГ и алгоритм правильного выбора параметров ?

Comment: Уважаемые закрывающие вопрос, что именно вам непонятно в сути этого вопроса? Все используемые термины общеизвестны, правила русского языка тоже не нарушаются...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кнут советует -

> "`m` выбирается как простое число, близкое к наибольшему легко вычисляемому целому числу, `a` полагается равным первообразному корню `m` и приращение `c` в этом случае равно нулю"

Это том второй, раздел 3.6.